# Filter Access 2010 Subreport by Criteria Not Used In Subreport

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, ms-access-2010, subreport

I have a subreport in Access 2010 that basically acts as an index/table of contents. The user can use a search form to filter projects by specific criteria. Only the matching reports should appear in the report and index. The report filters fine, but the Index doesn't.

Some of the criteria are directly in the index form, taken from an index table (area, year, projno). The rest are from an Activity table, and do not appear in the Index.

This is the code that I'm using to filter the Index with the criteria appearing in the index page, and it works fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM [INDEX] AS i
WHERE (
           i.ProjNo = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]) = 0    
    )
   AND
    (
           i.Prod = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProd]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtProd]) = 0
    )
   AND
    (
           i.year = Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]) = 0
    )
```

The problem occurs when I try and add fields from the activity table/that aren't in the Index.

This code

```
SELECT *
FROM [INDEX] AS i
WHERE (
           i.ProjNo = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]) = 0    
    )
   AND
    (
           i.Prod = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProd]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtProd]) = 0
    )
   AND
    (
           i.year = Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]) = 0
    )

  AND (SELECT *
FROM [ACTIVITY] AS a
WHERE (
           a.manager = Forms![SearchForm]![txtManager]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtManager]) = 0    
    ));
```

gives me a blank index, without even headings or page numbers.

SQL and Access are not my forte, and I would really appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a UNION query and also list out the specific fields.  The # of fields must be the same in both SELECT statements, and the fields must be the same data type.  For example, if Field1 is a Long, then Field4 should also be a long (see example below).

Like this:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM [INDEX] AS i
WHERE (
           i.ProjNo = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]) = 0    
    )
   AND
    (
           i.Prod = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProd]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtProd]) = 0
    )
   AND
    (
           i.year = Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]) = 0
    )

UNION

SELECT Field4, Field5, Field6
FROM [ACTIVITY] AS a
WHERE (
           a.manager = Forms![SearchForm]![txtManager]
        OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtManager]) = 0    
    )
```

Comment: When I try and run the report, it gives me a blank page.

Comment: Also, I have more fields in the `Activity` table than I do in the `Index` table.

Comment: OK, to use a UNION query, you MUST have the exact same number of fields, so for the Index table, you can put in some placeholders, like this:   UNION SELECT Field4, Field5, Field6, '','',0,0   ---- put single quotes for a text field and zeroes for a numeric field (these field types have to match up against the field types in the first SELECT statement).  Once you have the same number of fields, you might see data.